# Deadlock when trying to code a pool of worker methods

Tags: go, worker-pool

In the code hereunder, I don't understand why the "Worker" methods seem to exit instead of pulling values from the input channel "in" and processing them.

I had assumed they would only return after having consumed all input from the input channel "in" and processing them

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
)

type ParallelCallback func(chan int, chan Result, int, *sync.WaitGroup)

type Result struct {
    i   int
    val int
}

func Worker(in chan int, out chan Result, id int, wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
    for item := range in {
        item *= item // returns the square of the input value
        fmt.Printf("=> %d: %d\n", id, item)
        out <- Result{item, id}
    }
    wg.Done()
    fmt.Printf("%d exiting ", id)
}

func Run_parallel(n_workers int, in chan int, out chan Result, Worker ParallelCallback) {
    wg := sync.WaitGroup{}
    for id := 0; id < n_workers; id++ {
        fmt.Printf("Starting : %d\n", id)
        wg.Add(1)
        go Worker(in, out, id, &wg)
    }
    wg.Wait()  // wait for all workers to complete their tasks
    close(out) // close the output channel when all tasks are completed
}

const (
    NW = 4
)

func main() {
    in := make(chan int)
    out := make(chan Result)

    go func() {
        for i := 0; i < 100; i++ {
            in <- i
        }
        close(in)
    }()
    Run_parallel(NW, in, out, Worker)

    for item := range out {
        fmt.Printf("From out : %d: %d", item.i, item.val)
    }
}
```

The output is

```
Starting : 0
Starting : 1
Starting : 2
Starting : 3
=> 3: 0
=> 0: 1
=> 1: 4
=> 2: 9
fatal error: all goroutines are asleep - deadlock!
```

Comment: The workers cannot return until `in` is closed. Why do you think they are returning early?

Comment: That's basically the same question

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. You say "they seem to exit", but they are not exiting. What specifically is happening that you are not expecting?

Comment: I might be wrong about that and the problem might be elsewhere : I have added the output after the code in response to your comment. See output.

Comment: The error output will show where all goroutines are blocked. I assume you are blocked in `Run_parallel`, because you are not consuming from `out` until after `Run_parallel` returns.

Comment: You're right : the loop consuming out has to be started ahead and in parallel of  the call to Run_parallel.
Thanks !
See : Solution.

Comment: Please refrain from putting tags into question titles; also [the language is called Go](https://go.dev/doc/faq#go_or_golang).

Comment: tags in titles : what ?

Comment: `Golang:` is both not the name of the language, and not necessary in the title

Answer (score 3):

> fatal error: all goroutines are asleep - deadlock!

The full error shows where each goroutine is "stuck".  [If you run this in the playground](https://go.dev/play/p/E94OCsZFntZ), it will even show you the line number. That made it easy for me to diagnose.

Your `Run_parallel` runs in the `main` groutine, so before `main` can read from `out`, `Run_parallel` must  return.  Before `Run_parallel` can return, it must `wg.Wait()`.  But before the workers call `wg.Done()`, they must write to `out`.   That's what causes a deadlock.

One solution is simple: just run `Run_parallel` concurrently in its own Goroutine.

```
    go Run_parallel(NW, in, out, Worker)
```

Now, `main` ranges over `out`, waiting on `out`s closure to signal completion.  `Run_parallel` waits for the workers with `wg.Wait()`, and the workers will range over `in`.  All the work will get done, and the program won't end until it's all done.   (https://go.dev/play/p/oMrgH2U09tQ)

Answer (score -1):

Solution :

Run_parallel has to run in it’s own goroutine:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
)

type ParallelCallback func(chan int, chan Result, int, *sync.WaitGroup)

type Result struct {
    id  int
    val int
}

func Worker(in chan int, out chan Result, id int, wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
    defer wg.Done()
    for item := range in {
        item *= 2 // returns the double of the input value (Bogus handling of data)
        out <- Result{id, item}
    }
}

func Run_parallel(n_workers int, in chan int, out chan Result, Worker ParallelCallback) {
    wg := sync.WaitGroup{}
    for id := 0; id < n_workers; id++ {
        wg.Add(1)
        go Worker(in, out, id, &wg)
    }
    wg.Wait()  // wait for all workers to complete their tasks
    close(out) // close the output channel when all tasks are completed
}

const (
    NW = 8
)

func main() {

    in := make(chan int)
    out := make(chan Result)

    go func() {
        for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
            in <- i
        }
        close(in)
    }()

    go Run_parallel(NW, in, out, Worker)

    for item := range out {
        fmt.Printf("From out [%d]: %d\n", item.id, item.val)
    }

    println("- - - All done - - -")

}
```

Answer (score -1):

Alternative formulation of the solution:

In that alternative formulation , it is not necessary to start Run_parallel as a goroutine (it triggers its own goroutine).
I prefer that second solution, because it automates the fact that Run_parallel() has to run parallel to the main function. Also, for the same reason it's safer, less error-prone (no need to remember to run Run_parallel with the go keyword).

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
)

type ParallelCallback func(chan int, chan Result, int, *sync.WaitGroup)

type Result struct {
    id  int
    val int
}

func Worker(in chan int, out chan Result, id int, wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
    defer wg.Done()
    for item := range in {
        item *= 2 // returns the double of the input value (Bogus handling of data)
        out <- Result{id, item}
    }
}

func Run_parallel(n_workers int, in chan int, out chan Result, Worker ParallelCallback) {
    go func() {
        wg := sync.WaitGroup{}
        defer close(out) // close the output channel when all tasks are completed
        for id := 0; id < n_workers; id++ {
            wg.Add(1)
            go Worker(in, out, id, &wg)
        }
        wg.Wait() // wait for all workers to complete their tasks *and* trigger the -differed- close(out)
    }()
}

const (
    NW = 8
)

func main() {

    in := make(chan int)
    out := make(chan Result)

    go func() {
        defer close(in)
        for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
            in <- i
        }
    }()

    Run_parallel(NW, in, out, Worker)

    for item := range out {
        fmt.Printf("From out [%d]: %d\n", item.id, item.val)
    }

    println("- - - All done - - -")
}
```